# Rails, simple search for video object tags with acts-as-taggable-on gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

## routes.rb

```
resources :videos, except: [:create, :update] do
  collection do
    get "/search", to: "videos#search", as: "search"
  end
  resources :comments, except: [:show, :index]
end
```

## models/video.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, conditions: ['tag LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

## videos_controller.rb

```
def search
  @results = Video.search(params[:search])
end
```

## index.html.erb

```
<div class="">
  <%= form_tag search_videos_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <%= label_tag(:search, "Search") %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, "Search by video tag", params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Rails returns...

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for nil:NilClass
```

when loading the video index page, highlighting this line...

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, "Search by video tag", params[:search] %>
```

I also tried pointing the search towards videos controller index method and containing the logic and @results in there.

The acts-as-taggable-on gem gives each video an array of tags, each one a string. I am attempting to search for videos based on their tags within the videos index. I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I have forgotten to post any relevant code that might inform an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this.

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
```

The text "search by video tag" is for a label tag, outside of this.  You may have meant to add a placeholder option

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search by video tag" %>
```

Also, instead of this:

```
find(:all, conditions: ['tag LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

you can do this

```
tagged_with(search, :parse => true)
```

This will parse and split the tags if they use the separator and do an OR on the list.  You can control this in the options hash that's passed to the `tagged_with` method.

Answer (score 0):

As [Swards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177489/swards) suggested, removing the placeholder text helped however the search was still not functioning. Here's what ended up working...

## videos_controller.rb

```
  def search
    if params[:search]
      @results = Video.tagged_with(params[:search])
    end
  end
```

## views/videos/_search_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_videos_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <%= label_tag(:search, "Search") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

and I totally deleted the above posted code from #models/video.rb, which now looks like this...

## models/video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create { validates_presence_of :user, :post }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :comments

  validates :title, presence: true
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

Comment: Looks like you got all you needed from the earlier answer and solved your problem, but I don't see how this is an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you've found help from several sources.  lets see if we can clean it up a bit:

## 1 Search Results

There are 2 approaches with search, a.) display the results in the index page you already have, or b.) create a new route so the url says "/search" and users can bookmark if they wish -- I prefer the index approach, but you can do it either way.  To use the index approach, remove the route for search and change your controller to:

```
def index
  @videos = params[:search].nil? ? Video.all : Video.search(params[:search])
end
```

You'll also need to change the path for your form to `videos_path` from `search_videos_path` -- This way you only have to use one template.  If you want to continue with search as its own controller, action, that's perfectly fine too.  Rour routes and contoller can stay the same as they are now.

## 2 The model search

You aren't actually searching video table - you need to search the tag table.  The gem has a method for this, it's called `tagged_with`.  You also need to add an else statement, because you only want to return results of the search.  So update your model to look like:

```
  def self.search(search)
    videos = Video.tagged_with("#{search}", :any => true)
    return videos
  end
```

## 3 Make search text a placeholder

Change your form so that it's not using the text "Search by video tag" - but instead that is a placeholder (so users don't have to delete that before they start typing).  Also, you don't need to include the previous results, that's up to you.  if you do want them, you'll need to say `search: params[:search]`

```
  <%= form_tag search_videos_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <%= label_tag(:search, "Search") %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, "", placeholder: "Search by video tag" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the `video#search` refactor you suggest? It seems to work just fine as I have it now (posted in my answer) without any addition to the `#model/video.rb`. I tried both and they seem to function identically.